# Refreshing DataGridView after Backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in a form that uses a Backgroundworker to load the data and a pleasewait form to keep the UI responsive and show a gif so the user can see the item is still working.

After it is complete I need to somehow refresh the DataGridView with the new data. If i manually click on the headers to sort my ASC or DESC then it shows the up to date data. What or how is the best way to get this grid to refresh please?

```
    public void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pleaseWait.Show();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TestTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.TestTableData.TestTableTable, txtHotName.Text, ((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(txtDepartFrom.Text, typeof(System.DateTime)))), ((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(txtDepartTo.Text, typeof(System.DateTime)))), ((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(txtBookFrom.Text, typeof(System.DateTime)))), ((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(txtBookTo.Text, typeof(System.DateTime)))));
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        pleaseWait.Hide();
    }
```

The above does what it needs to which is great. I just need to some how refresh without having to make the end user re-order a column to actually show refreshed data.

Comment: Normally I would just clear and re-load the information into the DataGridView but I haven't used DGVs in a long time and there is probably a much better way of doing it. Sticking around to find out!

Comment: The re-paint method doesn't automatically get called when adding data to a DGV.  So the trick is to set the datagridview1.DataSource = null, and then back to the actual data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from jdweng's comment of ;

> The re-paint method doesn't automatically get called when adding data
>   to a DGV. So the trick is to set the datagridview1.DataSource = null,
>   and then back to the actual data source.

This fixed the option for me. My gif still spins and the UI updates as my criteria has changed.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        pleaseWait.Hide();
        this.TestTableTableDataGridView.DataSource = null;
        this.TestTableTableDataGridView.DataSource = TestTableTableBindingSource;
    }
```